# JavaScript - Create a new array with missing elements rather than re-mapping with undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

When selecting check boxes, I create an array with its corresponding value / index using the below line.

`days[dayCronValue] = dayString;`

If I select Thursday, output is as follows.

```
days
> [ , , , , 'Thursday']
```

If I select Saturday, output is as follows.

```
days
> [ , , , , 'Thursday', , 'Saturday']
```

This works perfectly as what gets saved is not the string, but its index.

```
'0 0 0 * * 4,6'
```

The problem I have is that my method to remove the days when unchecked cannot replace the existing element with a 'missing' element. I use the map method to replace it with undefined. My thought process below.

```
days
> [ , , , , 'Thursday', , 'Saturday']

days[0]
> undefined

days = days.map(day => day === dayString ? undefined : day);
```

Eg. If I uncheck Thursday, output is as follows.

```
days
> [ , , , , undefined, , 'Saturday']
```

The cronString which gets saved is still the same, as undefined still represents an existing index.

```
'0 0 0 * * 4,6'
```

My logic thinks I should just do a `forEach` method to iterate over `days` for any `typeof day !== 'undefined'` and use the `days[dayCronValue] = dayString` to build a new array. This way, it creates a new array with the correct indexes and correct elements.

I just can't figure out how to do that (or if I'm just over-complicating this process).

Cheers!

Comment: Just use for loop.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Is all you're trying to do to delete an element out of an array?  Just use `delete days[4]` if you want to get rid of that element.

Comment: @PMV That wouldn't work, because when the loop is iterated over, with let's say `for(var i in days){console.log(i);}`, this is logged: `0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6`

Comment: `delete days[4]` worked exactly.

Comment: @MasterBob - Maybe I missed the intent, but I thought that is what he wanted to happen - he wanted a sparse array that only defined certain particular indices.

Comment: Your `toCronString` function simply should not test for the existence of the property, but for the value not being `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, I didn't know it was called that but you're exactly spot on @PMV - if you want me to mark the question answered, can put it as an answer.

Comment: @Bergi - I did try altering the filter in my humanToCron function to `days = days.map(day => days.indexOf(day)).filter(day => typeof day !== 'undefined').join(',');` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rob I guess it would've worked if you had filtered the input, not the array of indices.

Comment: @Bergi - It does seem a lot clearer now that I'm no longer frustrated, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal here is to create a sparse array (where only a few particular indices are defined), then the answer is just to use `delete days[4]` to delete the day at index 4.

Comment: yeap, the delete operator is his friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var daystring = days.filter(day => day !== undefined).map((_, i) => i).join(',');
```

and don't need to care whether the properties don't exist of just don't contain a value. Notice that using `delete` on arrays, and using sparse arrays in general, is pretty bad for performance.

Comment: I don't think performance will be relevant in this case. The array length is 7.

Comment: @4castle Yeah, probably, though I still would avoid getting in the habit of using `delete` on arrays.